# give my own key in jce api for cryptography java

Tags: java, algorithm, security, cryptography

I want to use JCE API to crypt and decrypt file and string with DES algorithm
and I want to give my own key
but when I looked for an exemple I found that the key is generated like that :

```
    import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;


import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;


public class JEncrytion
{    
    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        try{

            KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
            SecretKey myDesKey = keygenerator.generateKey();
                    String key = "zertyuio";
            Cipher desCipher;

            // Create the cipher 
            desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");

            // Initialize the cipher for encryption
            desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);

            //sensitive information
            byte[] text = "No body can see me".getBytes();

            System.out.println("Text [Byte Format] : " + text);
            System.out.println("Text : " + new String(text));

            // Encrypt the text
            byte[] textEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(text);

            System.out.println("Text Encryted : " + textEncrypted);

            // Initialize the same cipher for decryption
            desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);

            // Decrypt the text
            byte[] textDecrypted = desCipher.doFinal(textEncrypted);

            System.out.println("Text Decryted : " + new String(textDecrypted));

        }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(NoSuchPaddingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(InvalidKeyException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IllegalBlockSizeException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(BadPaddingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }
}
```

do you have any idea

thank you in advance

Comment: Are you sure you want to use DES? DES is quite weak due to its small key.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the class `javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec`. It allows you to use a byte array holding the secret key.

The instance can then be passed to the `Cipher.init` method as the key.

Answer (score 3):

For DES you can create your secret key out of a [DESKeySpec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/DESKeySpec.html):

```
SecretKey myDesKey =
    SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES").generateSecret(new DESKeyspec(key.getBytes()));
```